# DataLake locks on read and write for the same file

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I have 2 different applications that handle data from Data Lake Storage Gen1.

The first application uploads files: if multiple uploads on the same day, the existing file will be overridden (it is always a file per day saved using the YYYY-MM-dd format)

The second application reads the data from the files.

Is there an option to lock this operations: when a write operation is performed, no read should take place and the same when a read happens the write should wait until the read operation is finished.

I did not find any option using the **AdlsClient**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, ADL gen1 is Apache Hadoop file system that's compatible with Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). So I searched some documents of HDFS and I'm afraid that you can't control mutual exclusion of reading and writing directly. Please see below documents:

1.link1: https://www.raviprak.com/research/hadoop/leaseManagement.html

> writers must obtain an exclusive lock for a file before they’d be
>   allowed to write / append / truncate data in those files. Notably,
>   this exclusive lock does NOT prevent other clients from reading the
>   file, (so a client could be writing a file, and at the same time
>   another could be reading the same file).

2.link2: https://blog.cloudera.com/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/

Before a client can write an HDFS file, it must obtain a lease, which is essentially a lock. This ensures the single-writer semantics. The lease must be renewed within a predefined period of time if the client wishes to keep writing. If a lease is not explicitly renewed or the client holding it dies, then it will expire. When this happens, HDFS will close the file and release the lease on behalf of the client so that other clients can write to the file. This process is called lease recovery.

---

I provide a workaround here for your reference: Adding a Redis database before your writes and reads!

No matter when you do read or write operations, firstly please judge whether there is a specific key in the Redis database. If not, write a set of key-value into Redis. Then do business logic processing. Finally don't forget to delete the key.

Although this is may a little bit cumbersome or affecting performance, I think it can meet your needs. BTW,considering that the business logic may fail or crash so that the key is never released, you can add the [TTL](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) setting when creating the key to avoid this situation.

Comment: I have implemented something similar with a custom lock

Comment: @Angela Cheers!